# ANTLR’s predicated-LL(*) parsing mechanism

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I'm building the following grammar:

```
Letter     : 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'     ; 

Number      : '0'..'9'     ; 

Float 
   :   Number+ '.' Number+  
   ; 

a5 
@init 
{ 
 int n = 1; 
} 
: ({n<=5}?=>(Letter|Number){n++;})+  
;
```

It not successfully parsed the string "CD923IJK", because I needs to be consumed "CD923" and not "CDIJK" like happening

If  FLoat is commented  the problem disappear and consumed "CD923" like I want

Obviously requires an advanced parsing, because this grammar is LL(K), I'm set the lookahead depth

```
options
{
k=5;
}
```

But not solved anything. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Response to the suggestion [500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/500-internal-server-error)
I added the following rule

```
public test :a5 Float   ;
```

I need to match CD9231.23 where CD923 is an alphanumeric and 1.23 a float. But see parse tree:
[image]

Comment: Is this your real grammar and input? It it is I don't see how the `Float` rule could match any of the input since you don't have a dot there.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This is a fragment of my grammar.The question is why this happened. Why "123" is skipped and consume in the 3 letters that follow the chain?

Comment: My suggestion would be to cut the grammar down to something you can post here in full along with the failing input.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I added an example in which I include the Float

Comment: Ok, what you appear to be trying to do here is to cut off the lexer from matching more than 5 characters for the `a5` symbol. I don't know ANTLR well enough to know if that's possible. FWIW, it would not be possible in the proprietary parser generator that I normally use. I will up-vote and hopefully an ANTLR expert will notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the rules Number and Float. You have an ambiguity in this two rules, but due both Number and Float are lexer rules, you must recall that antlr implicit create a nextToken rule to handle all the tokens. The nextToken in the example looks like this:

```
nextToken: Letter | Number | Float;
```

when antlr find a digit he walk through the DFA to find to which rule jump, but in this case he can't decide which is the proper rule (Number or Float) to jump to. You can avoid this behavior making the Float rule a parser rule. You can try something like this:

```
grammar a5;

s   : a5 coordinate? 
    ;

a5 
@init{
 int n = 0;
}
: ({n<5}?=> (LETTER|Number){n++;})+
;


Number  :   '0'..'9'
    ;

coordinate  :    Number+ '.' Number+
    ;

LETTER
    :   'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you could make a simpler solution: if you know that your a5 rule's items always will be a text of size 5 or less you can write the rule according to that:

```
A5 
: (Letter|Number)(Letter|Number)(Letter|Number)(Letter|Number)(Letter|Number) 
  | (Letter|Number)(Letter|Number)(Letter|Number)(Letter|Number) 
  | (Letter|Number)(Letter|Number)(Letter|Number) 
  | (Letter|Number)(Letter|Number) 
  | (Letter|Number) 
;
```

Other solution could be make the rule without taking in account the lenthg, and then checking it in a semantic phase:

```
AK 
    : (Letter|Number)+
;
```

This are some ideas, hope helps...